# Rent a car in Toronto and drive in the US with EU driving license

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, car-rentals

I am an EU citizen about to rent a car in Toronto with Alamo or Hertz and drive to the US East coast. I hold an EU driving license. My understanding is that I don't need an IDP to drive in Ontario and in the US as a visitor (< 3 months).
I already got my ESTA approved, but it seems I also need to fill an I-94 form: https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1258?language=en_US. Can this be done at the border or it needs to be done beforehand ?

Also, Hertz mentions: *It is recommended to have PERS cover when using vehicle in cross border rentals for the USA and Canada.*
Since I plan to drive to NYC, where there are plenty of tolls, I wonder if it's possible to pay at the booth or it's all linked to the car plate (or a toll system) and then settled with the car rental company ? If so, will the car rental company charge extra fees ?

Finally, after reading this post: [Renting a car in the USA — how to know costs for the legal minimum liability insurance, before arriving for pickup?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44551/renting-a-car-in-the-usa-how-to-know-costs-for-the-legal-minimum-liability-ins), I would like to know if a rental car in Canada comes with appropriate insurance (similar to the EU) or if I should purchase some extra insurance at the counter.

Thank you!

Comment: There are many questions here. I'll address the tolls.You should get an [EZPass transponder](https://www.ny.gov/services/get-e-zpass), which will allow you to pay for toll roads, tunnels, bridges, and sometimes parking in many states. Without it, sometimes you will have to look for coins and wait in line to pay toll. Many times, the toll collection system will photograph your car's license number and bill you later, but it will cost a little more that with the transponder.

Comment: Also "My understanding is that I don't need an IDP to drive in Ontario and in the US as a visitor" if your foreign license is not printed in English, then you need a certified translation or the IDP.  If it is in English, then you don't need either. Source https://dmv.ny.gov/more-info/resources-non-us-citizens

Comment: IDK how the Canada/US automated toll roads work (i.e. no payment booths but ANPR), but in UK the rental agency would get a **penalty charge** if the fee isn't paid by the end of the following day.

Comment: I don't know if you can actually get this from Hertz in Canada, but Hertz offers [Plate Pass](https://www.hertz.ca/rentacar/productservice/index.jsp?targetPage=USplatepass.jsp&leftNavUserSelection=globNav_3_5_1&selectedRegion=United%20States) for tolls in the US.  (I don't know, because that link is to a CA website, but seems to point to a US service)

Comment: @PeterM I recommend not renting from Hertz - please see https://www.autoblog.com/2022/02/14/hertz-customers-stolen-car-reports/ .

Comment: You also should check with the rental car agency that you're allowed to take their car out of the country.

Comment: Echo what @MichaelLugo said! I (US citizen) rented a car in Vienna and was specifically asked if I was planning to leave the country. Also, some places (like Chicago, IL - not on the intended route) offer the opportunity to pay tolls online after the fact (for the same rate as an EZ Pass), but require cash or card to pay on others.

Comment: You also don't need to fill in an i-94 form. This is issued electronically by a CBP officer when you present yourself to them upon arrival